# extract the content from docx file using phpword createReader

Tags: laravel, phpword

i want to extract content from docx file while uploading but i'm getting this error: Object of class PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord could not be converted to string
Any Solution please let me know ?

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
             'file'=>'required|mimes:doc,pdf,docx'
         ]);

      if($request->hasFile('file')) {
           $file= $request->file('file');
            $fileName = time() .'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
               $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

            $obj = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader($phpWord, 'Word2007');
            $obj->load($fileName);

            $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($obj, 'Word2007');
            try {
             $objWriter->save(storage_path('my.docx'));
            } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
             return response()->download(storage_path('my.docx'));

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
public function store(Request $request){


  $this->validate($request, [
    'file'=>'required|mimes:docx,doc'
  ]);
  $fatwa = new Fatwa;
  if($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $file= $request->file('file');


    $objReader= \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('Word2007');
    $phpWord= $objReader->load($file);

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    try {
      $objWriter->save(storage_path('my.docx'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
    return response()->download(storage_path('my.docx'));

  }

}
```